# How to insert or push_back with unordered_mp of vectors

Tags: c++, vector, unordered-map

I have a vector of nums:

```
nums = [2, 3, -2, 4]
```

and I have an `std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<int>> m` in which I iterate though nums and calculate the the contiguous product and insert the index pairs.

In other words I want this from `m`

```
key  value
6  [0, 1]
-6  [1, 2]
-8  [2, 3]
```

I have not been able to figure out how to achieve this. But this is what I have tried:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> nums = {2, 3, -2, 4};
    std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<int>> m;
    int prod_max = INT_MAX;
    for(int i = 1; i < nums.size(); ++i)
    {
        prod_max = std::min(prod_max, nums[i-1]*nums[i]);
        m.at(prod_max).push_back({i-1, i});
    }

    for(auto it : m)
    {
        std::cout << it.first << "\n";
    }    
}
```

Perhaps since this causes no compiler errors. I did this correctly, if so this will be even easier of a question: How do I print the keys and the vector values?

Comment: I don't see the relationship between `nums` and your example unordered map layout. Could you please explain?

Comment: @ifconfig Could you clarify what you mean? I am not sure  understand.

Comment: Sure! My question is: how does the data in the `nums` vector translate to the data you want to populate into the `m` unordered map?

Comment: @ifconfig Yes, so this probably will be more supporting https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-product-subarray/. My idea is to store the prod_max as the key and return the associated nums that have the maximum product.

Comment: You should focus on smaller problems, then build larger solutions on smaller ones. You admitted that your code might be correct, so you need the output. How to print the keys and the vector values? Well, if your map was from `int` to `int`, could you print out the keys and integer values (i.e. how to print a map)? If you have a vector, could you print out the vector? If you had both of these pieces, could you combine them to get your desired output? [Which of these steps do you need help with?]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do here is push a vector to a vector. Since

> m.at(prod_max)

Gives a vector of type int, you cannot push another vector to it. Doing:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> nums = {2, 3, -2, 4};
    std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<int>> m;
    int prod_max = INT_MAX;
    for(int i = 1; i < nums.size(); ++i)
    {
        prod_max = std::min(prod_max, nums[i-1]*nums[i]);
        m[prod_max] = {i-1, i};
    }

    for(auto it : m)
    {
        std::cout << it.first << "\t";
        for(auto it2: it.second)
            std::cout << it2 << ",";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }    
}
```

Gives me what you want

Edit** Sorry, I just realized you wanted both keys and values printed. I've updated my code to reflect that.